# How to find a British agency that will publish a book in Russia?

Tags: publishing, self-publishing, agent

How can I find a British agency to represent me as a writer in Russia in order to publish a book there (a book written originally in Russian)? Do such agencies exist?

I understand that it does sound screwy, however. The reason why I would prefer a British agency rather than a Russian one is simple: I am UK based and I feel that it would be easier to communicate.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is probably to get yourself an agent first of all, as any decent operation will have contacts in other markets.

However there are large international agencies for which this would be a more natural fit: http://www.andrewnurnberg.com/ spring to mind.